# Is there an api in .net to display objects from sql in an applicaiton?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I'm looking for an API that will allow me to display database objects in a web or desktop UI. Does anyone know of any?

I'm trying to display schema and tables from a specific database so that the user of this tool can create ad hoc reports. If a user selects a table, I want them to be able to see column information as well.

I summary, the tool is supposed to be like SSIS but in a web application.

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_

Comment: just query the system tables to find the data you need (this is all Sql Management studio does). Sys.objects, sys.columns, etc...

Comment: There are at least three different ways in the BCL alone. Google is probably where you should be looking, or MSDN.

Comment: @Matt: The database access API should be wrapping those neatly as C# enumerators, etc.

Comment: I expect that unless you can be a lot more specific about what you need this question will be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162557.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

You can create LINQ to SQL classes using MS Visual Studio. That will let you see tables and their associations to one another.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384428.aspx